# importing pro tools session data into digital performer

Tags: pro-tools, workflow

The mixer I'm working is using Digital Performer. Is it even possible to import Pro Tools session data into Digital Performer? Or will I have to bounce each track down as a .wav file one by one?

Also, the production sound on one of the scenes went missing. The recordist somehow lost it. Is it even possible salvage this audio?       [camera audio](http://soundcloud.com/mitchell-scott/camera-audio) by [Mitchell Scott](http://soundcloud.com/mitchell-scott)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Can DP export OMF's? - try exporting from DP into PT this way.

If I remember correctly PT wont take DP automation settings so you will need to bounce the tracks if you had any complex automation. (Unless DP has come out with a version that has in the past 3 years that will accept OMF's and the corresponding automation)

Missing audio? That usually means the audio has moved from whatever directory the audio was originally imported from. Try moving it back. If its completely gone... thats the nightmarish scenario.

Can anyone confirm my DP speculations?

Comment: @C3Sound Sorry I meant to clarify that the audio was lost from the production sessions, so they don't have the audio for that scene. I was thinking ADR, but if it can be avoided then all the better. 